# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, gradle, dex

After switching from `gradle:2.3.3` to `gradle:3.0.1` I have problem with dex merging.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Here is my gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'

    //    Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    //    RX
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'

    //Butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why I should get this error.

Answer (score 0):

check app\libs for external library.

clean project
rebuild project